# Excel Add-In not loading COM add-in at runtime

Tags: .net, excel, add-in

We have created a Excel Add-In in VB .Net using ExcelDNA.
This Add-In also creates a COM Add-In dynamically, that creates a Custom Task Pane in Excel.

This has been working on our client machine, however for some reason the Custom Task Pane Add-In disappears. As you can see from the below image there are 2 Add-Ins, which is correct, but on our client machine it shows 1 Add-In i.e. only the Excel Add-In, but it was working on their machine before.

WE have already tried the following:

o   Removed all the conflicting addins

o   Uninstalled and re installed our RDA

o   Checked the registry entry for RDA

o   Re-added the RDA addin via excel addins -> Go

o   Disabled the anti-virus

o   Copied the the dll and .xll file from a working machine to the client machine.

Nothing seems to work.....

[image: Addin]

Comment: Have you checked for 'Disabled Items' on the add-ins page (at the bottom, next to 'Manage')?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing there, the strange thing is it was working on their computer before, and it is the only computer that it is not working, we tried alot of other computers and it works.